# GitHub API v4: How can I traverse with pagination? (GraphQL)

Tags: rest, github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I'm using Github API v4 to run search query.

From the API documentation I can understand that the following query gives me pageInfo but I don't know how to use it to traverse.

```
query {
  search(first: 100, type:USER, query:"location:usa repos:>0 language:java") {
    pageInfo {
      startCursor
      hasNextPage
      endCursor
    }
    userCount
    nodes {
        ... on User {
        bio
        company
        email
        id
        isBountyHunter
        isCampusExpert
        isDeveloperProgramMember
        isEmployee
        isHireable
        isSiteAdmin
        isViewer
        location
        login
        name
        url
        websiteUrl
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And response is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "search": {
            "pageInfo": {
                "startCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOjE=",
                "hasNextPage": true,
                "endCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOjEwMA=="
            },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to [graphql documentation](http://graphql.org/learn/pagination/) there are more than one pagination model.

GitHub is using **complete connection model**

In this model you can traverse with adding **after:"Y3Vyc29yOjEwMA=="** to your search query.

```
query {
  search(first: 100, after:"Y3Vyc29yOjEwMA==", type:USER, query:"location:usa repos:>0 language:java") {
    pageInfo {
      startCursor
      hasNextPage
      endCursor
    }
    userCount
    nodes {
        ... on User {
        bio
        company
        email
        id
        isBountyHunter
        isCampusExpert
        isDeveloperProgramMember
        isEmployee
        isHireable
        isSiteAdmin
        isViewer
        location
        login
        name
        url
        websiteUrl
      }
    }
  }
}
```