# How to search specific page through GitHub API V4

Tags: github-api, github-api-v4

Github APIv4 GraphQL has some good features but I cant find a way to search issues using **pagination** like

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:user/somerepo+is:open&page=10&per_page=100
```

Is there a way to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116781/github-api-v4-how-can-i-traverse-with-pagination-graphql)

Comment: @BertrandMartel Thanks.But this after parameter can only go to the next page. I want to know how to skip to the specified page,like page 1 to page 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Github GraphQL api uses a cursor to iterate through the results. But, there is no documentation on the cursor format and it seems that, for the search query it just base64 encode the string `cursor:<digit>`

You can check this when you specify `pageInfo { endCursor }` :

```graphql
query { 
  search(type:ISSUE, query:"repo:mui-org/material-ui is:issue", first: 100){
        nodes {
      ... on Issue {
        number
        title
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
    }
  }
}
```

It gives :

```graphql
"pageInfo": {
   "endCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOjEwMA=="
}
```

And if you decode `Y3Vyc29yOjEwMA==` in base64 it gives : `cursor:100` so it's not a real cursor and you can use this to paginate the same way as in Rest API v3 (for instance skipping page as you suggested)

Let's say you want the page 10 directly with 100 items per page, it would be `cursor:900` which gives `Y3Vyc29yOjkwMA==` base64 encoded :

```graphql
{
  search(type: ISSUE, query: "repo:mui-org/material-ui is:issue", first: 100, after:"Y3Vyc29yOjkwMA==") {
    nodes {
      ... on Issue {
        number
        title
      }
      
    }
    issueCount
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
    }
  }
}
```

A programmatic approach would be to add `after: base64("cursor:<item_num>")` with item_num starting from 0 (`after:"Y3Vyc29yOjA="`) to X. You can know X by requesting `issueCount` value the first time (or in an initial request depending on your usecase)

Note that there is a limit of 1000 results for the Github search API so you can't access page > 10 with per_page=100 theoretically for instance : https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:mui-org/material-ui&page=11&per_page=100 (the same restriction applies for GraphQL)

Also note that the cursor format seems to change depending on the query type, the above answer only applies for `search` query. For instance, checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336529/2614364) for the commit cursor format

Comment: The glory days are over it seems. I tried that for several different repos, but the cursor string (decoded) was always something like `b'cursor:v2:\\x92\\x00\\xce\\x0fu\\x07\\xb1'`.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer do you have a specific repo/request that return this cursor format ? was it with `type: ISSUE` ?

Comment: I'm looking at stargazers. Upon further inspection, I see that it _returns_ the `v2` cursor, but I think that it accepts the original cursor you propose as well. Playing around with it right now to verify.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Maybe it's a recent addition not yet deployed on the whole network. I still get the original cursor for example [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/34a3db0a8f223a9d14f07ddaa0329d49) return `cursor:100` for me

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/nschloe/230532a648c0589362644bd42d0e68ee) gives cursorv2.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer that's interesting, I've tried on aws ireland zone to see if it was only my location but it also returns `cursor:100`. I will check again in a few days

Comment: I've added some curl versions at https://github.community/t/get-stargazer-time-with-custom-cursor/171929 (together with what doesn't work) in case you're interested.