# Retrieve a report with all admins for each repo in a GitHub org using GitHub API and scripting

Tags: github, github-api

Currently I don't see any easy way to generate a report that has the list of admins for each repo within a GitHub org. The below example works for me great to retrieve the list of admins for a single repo :

```bash
curl https://my-github-url/api/v3/repos/my-org/my-repo/collaborators?per_page=100 \
     -H "Authorization: Token my-valid-token" | \
     jq '[ .[] | select(.permissions.admin == true) | .login ]'
```

Is there a way to iterate this for all the repos under that org and then generate a fancy report probably like a html tabular report or probably excel type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to reduce the number of request using the following :

```graphql
{
  organization(login: "your-org") {
    repositories(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        nameWithOwner
        collaborators(first: 100) {
          totalCount
          edges {
            permission
            node {
              login
              name
            }
          }
          pageInfo {
            endCursor
            hasNextPage
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which gives :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "organization": {
      "repositories": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "nameWithOwner": "Your-Org/Your-Repo",
            "collaborators": {
              "totalCount": 18,
              "edges": [
                {
                  "permission": "ADMIN",
                  "node": {
                    "login": "johndoe",
                    "name": "John Doe"
                  }
                },
                ............................
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An example using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```bash
#!/bin/bash

token="YOUR_TOKEN"
org="YOUR_ORG"

query='{
  organization(login: \"'$org'\") {
    repositories(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        nameWithOwner
        collaborators(first: 100) {
          totalCount
          edges {
            permission
            node {
              login
              name
            }
          }
          pageInfo {
            endCursor
            hasNextPage
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
curl -s -H "Authorization: token $token" \
     -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "'"${query//[$'\n|\r\n']}"'"
      }' https://api.github.com/graphql | jq '.data.organization.repositories.nodes[] | 
        {
            repo: .nameWithOwner, 
            users: [
                .collaborators.edges[] | 
                select(.permission == "ADMIN") | 
                .node
            ]
        }'
```

If you have more than 100 repo or more than 100 collaborators, you would need to manage [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116781/github-api-v4-how-can-i-traverse-with-pagination-graphql)

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. That worked great for me for an org with just five repos. I got the correct list of admins. However i need to try this for an org with 500 plus repositories. How do i use pagination to do so. I am fully novice in this area?